# How to dynamically change bootstrap 4 modal data submitted by button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Folks 
I am using bootstrap 4 madal.

The use case is that user clicks edit button and it sends current data (being sourced from database) to the modal. User edits the modal and submit, this calls js function which updates database.
If I refresh the page, I have no problems but I do not want to do that since most of this data is dynamically added with scroll down. and refreshing the page sends the user back to the top. so I though of using jquery to update the database and simply update form data dynamically, so user can continues where he stands.

I have a button that basically launches a modal in a editable form and sends data-title to the modal

```
<button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-title="Post 1">Edit</button>
```

modal input looks like following

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="edit(this.form)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This modal receives the data of course by solution provided by bootstrap 4

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  var recipient = button.data('title')
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-body input#title').val(recipient)
})
```

User updates the field and sends the change to edit function

```
function edit(form){
  var title = form.title.value;
  ////// insert into database
  var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
  btn1.setAttribute( 'data-title' ,form.title.value );
  alert(title);
}
```

now as you can see that after inserting the data, function will update "data-title" to the newly added value by user. I can see this in "inspect-element"....

**PROBLEM**
**However, each re-occurrence of the same action sends old data**

for example
lets say data came from database is "Post 1"

[image]

As you can see the value is 
[image]

Now the user changes it to "Post 2", and clicks submit

This is new value now
[image]

This is all good, However if lets say user clicks on edit button again, theoratically the new value set for "data-title" should be sent to modal, but modal comes back with the same old "Post-1"

I searched online and apparently I need to set something for "show.bs.modal" and clear the form but non of them are working.

what am I missing. 
here is codepen

https://codepen.io/ozzie6935/pen/bQpmjY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `.data` method is retrieving cached `data-` attributes from jQuery's data object (see [this](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)), which means that they will not be updated when you change corresponding DOM element attributes. Use `.attr()` instead.

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  var recipient = button.attr('data-title')
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-body input#title').val(recipient)
})
```

Here is an [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/mkrl/pen/ZmWVMJ) of yours.